# Order of constants and variables when typesetting equations

Tags: notation, article-writing

I seem to recall that when writing mathematics, constants appear first (numerals, then symbols in alphabetical order) and then variables follow (alphabetically). A simple example would be: 2 \pi x. In the text that I am writing, the equations are significantly more complex.

What is the rule for how these things are supposed to be written?